# What is the default test framework for ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, testing

**tl;dr**: It's so difficult to run a basic test run

By using `Create-React-App` to scaffolding a new project, it will include default `App.test.js` with below content:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);

  //expect(div.innerHTML).toContain('Hi There!');

  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});
```

I've tried to run command `yarn test`, below is the response i got

> Error: Cannot find module '/Users/isaaclem/Code/ReactJS/testing/node_modules/jest-cli'

And if I try `npm run test` instead, I'm hitting same error too, which saying couldnt find `jest-cli`. Is there any reason where `C-R-A` gives us a default test file but not including the necessary framework/module?

Below is the default `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "testing",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

**UPDATES:**

I've then execute the command `npm install --save jest-cli` to install the missing dependencies and try running the test again and hitting the below error instead:

```
Determining test suites to run...
--watch is not supported without git/hg, please use --watchAll
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! testing@0.1.0 test: `react-scripts test --env=jsdom`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the testing@0.1.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

A lil research on this error, it seems that we need `git init` to solve the problem and hence I've running git init command and indeed it solved the problem which then throwing me yet another new problem.

[image]

Comment: Have a look on this conversation, hope it helps: https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript/issues/154

Comment: @gazdagergo: Indeed solved all the issues I'm facing! Thanks a lot!